# New to Oracle BI

Tags: obiee

I used some reporting platforms ( SAP Business Objects and some other third party applications). I have pl-sql experience but I am new to Oracle BI.
At this point, I have some questions which confuses my mind.
First one is there are lots of terminology in Oracle BI but I do not know which products should I know, or in which order I can learn and experience these platforms.
For example you can create dashboards, analysis by Oracle BI. Terms/products like Essbase, Hyperion, Warehouse Builder, ODI etc.

My second question is :
I want to install Oracle 11g and Oracle BI 11 in the same pc. But I hearded and read on some forums that they are not working on  the same computer. But I want to setup BI tool to my personal computer for practicing in my home. How can I install these two products in my pc? ( My pc is 64 bit)

Thanks&Regards

Answer (score 1):

Just dot it ;-)
http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/installation_11.1

You can have a database and obiee on the same machine.

Cheers
Nico

Comment: ,computrec: Is Oracle Business Intelligence, v. 11.1.1.5.0  free to install?

Comment: almost everything can be downloaded from Oracle OTN site for free and free to use on a development machine - I love this part about Oracle :) but once you are ready to use it in production, you would have to pay

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Oracle DB 11g followed by the latest OBIEE 11g installation. (note that you need to install RCU before you proceed with the OBIEE 11g install). You can get both of them from otn.oracle.com. The Install documentation can guide you in the entire setup; and hopefully there should be no surprises.

After that, install the Sample App and follow the instructions to create new analysis, dashboards etc. After this, am sure you will be upto speed with the terminologies and the workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post on wiki - should give you basic understanding on OBIEE stack

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Business_Intelligence_Suite_Enterprise_Edition

you mentioned Warehouse Builder - Oracle steering away from it, so ODI will be a choice of ETL tool.

Answer (score 0):

You have a long journey ahead of you for OBIEE so, sit back, relax and enjoy the ride. You want to start with the BI Foundation which includes BI Server and Answers, before moving on to products like Essbase, Hyperion, Warehouse Builder, ODI etc.

I would start by

1. [Doing a simple install of OBIEE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10539/toc.htm). I prefer Linux but you can use Windows as well. 8GB would be nice. Each of the following has a graphical install wizard which guides you through the choices.

   a. Install the DB

   b. Run the RCU

   c. Install OBIEE

   d. Install BI Admin tool for creating or modifying the repository
2. Do some [tutorials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-enterprise-edition/tutorials/obiee11g-453435.html) provided by Oracle. I would start with the following and in this order.

   a. Creating a Repository Using the Oracle BI 11g Administration Tool - MANDATORY if you are a serious OBIEE professional

   b. Creating Analyses and Building Dashboards - For Adhoc Analysis - Important

   c. Getting Started with Oracle BI Publisher - OPTIONAL - If you care for published or printed reports or for some quick and dirty reporting, without having to create a model in the repository.

You want to avoid these [common mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056537/244461) if you are installing on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Oracle 11g ad Oracle BI in the same machine without any issue. 
As far as the second question is concerned, you can create your reports with the knowledge of only Oracle BI , pl/sql and 11g. Pl/Sql is required to writhe pre and post procesors for the report. ESS will only be required to schedule the report and as such you won't require it in the learning phase. You can learn it later