# RCU Installation issues

Tags: oracle, failed-installation, obiee

I am trying to install Obiee11g on my windows machine. While running through various tutorials in the web, many of them have suggested to use RCU to create MDS and BIplatform.

However when I downloaded RCU and extracted the same. While I am running the rcu.bat in the running directory, it is just opening my OBIEE_HOME folder. I am not able to see the RCU window.

Please Help!

Cheers,
Dwarak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder named ***OBIEE*** in the drive where you are trying to install OBIEE !!

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of specific error information, I will provide you some generic instructions on how to run the RCU.

1. Make sure your machine is compliant. I prefer Linux but for Windows, **I would use x86-64 2003 / 2008 Windows server.**
2. Open a command shell
3. Execute rcu.bat
4. Follow the prompts
5. Record the error and upload that for further assistance.

**Some of the most common errors are:**

1. Lack of disk space.
2. Low RAM
3. Avoid running Oracle DB on the same machine where you are running OBIEE, for performance reasons.
4. Unzip the RCU shiphome in a folder without spaces
5. Cleanup your PATH variable which might be pointing to older BI installations
6. %TMP% and %TEMP% paths should not have spaces either.
7. Do not set ORACLE_HOME
8. Do not set JAVA_HOME
9. Properly de-install previous products

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a space in the directory where the RCU is installed.